# Deleting documents from collection in Pymongo?

Tags: python, pymongo

I have the following:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db=client.localhost
collection=db['accounts']
db.collection.remove({})

cursor = collection.find({})
for document in cursor:
    print(document)
```

This second part is to just print all the documents in the collection. However, the collection isn't clearing every time I rerun the program. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Problem is that you are using `db.collection` (which points to collection named "collection") instead of the `collection` variable (which points to "accounts"), so you are cleaning the wrong collections

Answer (score 2):

Just do this

```
db.accounts.drop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
db.collection.remove({})
```

you can try this

```
collection.delete_many({})
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this

```
db.collection.remove({})
```

do this

```
db.accounts.remove({})
```

Also you won't need this line `collection=db['accounts']`

If you want dynamic collection name, you can do the following:

```
collection_name = 'accounts'
getattr(db, collection_name).remove({})
```